# How to fix ( $ is not a function ) for gulp building js file?

Tags: wordpress, gulp

I got an error: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function at app.min.js?ver=5.6.2:1 I know there are many answers to this question. But not in my case. For developing a theme, I am using gulp. So the app.min.js The file is constantly changing during development and I can't just add:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

});
```

If we were talking about a finished project, it always helps me. But not at this time. Here is part of my gulp file who is responsible for creating: app.min.js

```
function scripts() {
 return src([ 
    '../themes/themename/js/vendor/ajax-mail.js',
    '../themes/themename/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js',
    '../themes/themename/js/vendor/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js',
    '../themes/themename/js/vendor/isotope.pkgd.min.js',
    '../themes/themename/js/vendor/jquery.counterup.min.js',
    '../themes/themename/js/vendor/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
    '../themes/themename/js/vendor/owl.carousel.min.js',
    '../themes/themename/js/vendor/plugins.js',
    '../themes/themename/js/vendor/popper.js',
    '../themes/themename/js/vendor/waypoints.min.js',
    '../themes/themename/js/app.js',
    ])
      .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(dest('../themes/themename/js'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream())
   }
```

Maybe there is some way to automatically frame all content of the app.min.js in

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 });
```

I cannot find a solution, I will be glad for the help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see jQuery in your plugins src. If you're using WordPress jQuery, make sure, your app.min.js depends on it

Comment: this is line from functions.php : 
wp_enqueue_script( 'themename-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/app.min.js', array('jquery') );